# For h $\in \mathbb R$ and $h \gt -1$ and n $\in \mathbb N$: prove $1 + n \cdot h \le (1 + h)^n$

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

I try to prove this using contradiction, but something tells me this is not a valid proof.

Suppose it's not true, and suppose $h \lt 0$.

Then we get that $(1 + h)^n \gt 1$ and $1 + n \cdot h \lt 1$ which is a contradiction.

Is this a valid proof?

The other way I tried proving was supposing that $h \lt 0$ on the one hand, and $h \gt 0$ on the other. But that doesn't get me anywhere actually.

So if I use binomial expansion like Pratyush Sarkar said, I get this:

$1 + n \cdot h \le \binom{n}{0} h^0 + \binom{n}{1}h^1 + ... + \binom{n}{n}h^n$

$= 1 + n \cdot h \le 1 + n \cdot h + ... + 1 \cdot h^n$

This means that the right part equals (the left part + more). Meaning the right part is bigger. This will always be the case if $h \gt 0$. So now I'm going to try and prove the case where $h \lt 0$.

Comment: Can't you just use binomial expansion?

Comment: Hint: use mathematical induction.

Comment: About your proof: why do you assume that $h\lt0$ (a proof by contradiction is supposed to find a contradiction for every $h$ in the range $h\gt-1$)? And how do you know that $(1+h)^n\gt1$ (it is not true)?

Comment: Well that was where I doubted. h can be $\lt 0$ so I took that case. And that case only leads to a contradiction. So I understand now that this is not a good approach. And if I suppose that $h \lt 0 and \gt -1$ I know that $1 + h$ is going to be less than 1... (I just saw my mistake...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if $h < 0$ then you get $(1 + h)^n < 1$, not $(1 + h)^n > 1$.  You can do the following with induction.  For $n = 1$ clearly $(1 + h)^n \geq 1 + nh$ because get equality.  So then assume $(1 + h)^n \geq 1 + nh$.  Then because $1 + h > 0$, you can multiply the inequality by $(1+h)$ to get 
$$(1 + h)^{n+1} \geq (1+nh)(1+h) = 1 + (n+1)h + nh^2$$,

and the right hand side is greater than or equal to $1 + (n+1)h$ because $nh^2 \geq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

The positive case can be taken care of by the binomial theorem.

Comment: This is correct too. I've used this way to prove the positive case, and induction for the negative case.